# MATLAB: Linear Indexing Multidimensions

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to assign some values to a matrix.In the case of 2 or 3 dimension, it is easy to use sub2ind. However the data I use has 23 dimensions. The situation could be explained better with an example. `A` is a matrix which has `3x4x5x6x7`dimensions. I want to assign something to `A(1,2,3,4,5)` with linear indexing. Normally, it is possible with sub2ind like:

```
A(sub2ind(siz,1,2,3,4,5)) = any_var;
```

However the thing I want is that assigning the sub2ind input with an array instead of commas. Is there anything which satisfies this in MATLAB?

```
A(sub2ind(siz,[1 2 3 4 5])) = any_var; % I want something like this.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define the vector with the index values

```
x = [1 2 3 4 5];
```

Then you can convert to cell (using [`num2cell`](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html)) and from that to a [comma-separated list](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html):

```
xc = num2cell(x);
A(sub2ind(siz, xc{:})) = any_var;
```

Or you could do the computation directly and avoid `sub2ind`. To convert to linear index, subtract 1 from the index along the *k*-th dimension and multiply by the cumulative product of the sizes of the preceding dimensions. The sum for all *k* plus 1 is the linear index:

```
A(x(1) + sum((x(2:end)-1).*cumprod(siz(1:end-1)))) = any_var;
```

Comment: Is it faster? (The second solution)

Comment: Idea of `cumprod` looks right to me. I have used the same strategy to collapse rows of a 2D array into scalar each to give a 1D array such that each row is assumed to represent the linear index equivalents when mapped to a n-dim grid, where `n` is  the no. of cols. So, in NumPy that would become a crazy one-liner : `a.dot(np.append((a.max(0)+1)[:0:-1].cumprod()[::-1],1))`! That indexing part `[:0:-1]` I thought was sick though ;)